# How write the correct load data infile command?

Tags: mysql, centos

Below is my sample data.MY environment is centos and I have run this command to make all into a single space sed 's/  */\ /g'  but unfortunately the spaces are still not uniform. Any solution?

```
308589422           3.10882 101.54966            23           0              215         0.9          2011-08-01 00:00:00        1              00402020F028    00                000         0              00           109.6     13033    4D           \N                           \N           \N           \N           \N           \N
308590571           5.00517 102.22741            20           0              340         0              2011-08-01 00:00:00        1              00000000             27.3                012         0              04.0        154856  BB1012                 \N                           \N           \N           01           0100       0
308596673           2.94121 101.76445            29           0              62           0              2011-08-01 00:00:00        1              00000000             25.4                000         0              04.1        56870.5 AB0569                 \N                           \N           \N           02           0000       F
308596708           3.99147 101.05772            15           0              105         0              2011-08-01 00:00:00        1              00000000             12.6                01B         0              04.1        42562.9 AB0829                 \N                           \N           \N           02           0000       F
308589424           5.4142   100.55539            26           0              126         1              2011-08-01 00:00:01        1              01000028F820    57                3FF         0              F5           1082.31 13276    75           \N                           \N           \N           \N           \N           \N
308589482           4.95754 102.07095            3              96           235         0              2011-08-01 00:00:01        1              00000000             27.0                000         0              04.1        10278.9 BB1788                 \N                           \N           \N           01           0100       F
```

Comment: The title of this question seems unrelated to the content. What is your question exactly?

Comment: My question is how to load the data back into my db the problem it have not uniform spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend sed 's/\s+/ /g' (\s+ matching any repeatable whitespace , not only space char)

Comment: Ok I am trying it now and will feedback to you soon

Comment: I have tried but the space remain the same? So what should I do?

Comment: I tried this sed 's/  */\ /g' it works fine for the first seven row where I purposely extract the the 7 rows into a new files. Then I apply to the bigger file with the seven rows and other rows no changes happened even to the first 7 seven rows a bit funny here?